# git cant authentication

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github

I'm a developer that has switched to ubuntu and I can't get git to work. I have logged in to git but I still get

```
> git push origin main:main
remote: No anonymous write access.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/zaze06/Tetris.git'
```

when I try to update the code on GitHub from what's on my PC
I'm running

- Ubuntu: 20.04
- git: 2.25.1
- visual studio code: 1.62.2

Comment: This is a question about `git`. You need to setup git, so it has a login.

Comment: then how because fro what I have found on searches doesn't work

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Github has a perfect help.

Comment: then I'm just bad at searching or something like that

Comment: I found [this](https://techglimpse.com/git-push-github-token-based-passwordless/) but it didn't work so do you know of a guide or what it's called?

Comment: ok it kinda worked it worked in the way of I can push a commit to GitHub but vscode cant do it by itself

Comment: You either need to use anonymous http to access a git repository, in read only mode, or password authenticated https, or an ssh key exchange.  The later is the preferred way to use git.  Git will use your default ssh keys if you have them,you just need configure your account on the git repository with your public key, so it can identify your push requests as coming from you

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
git config --global user.name "your_username"
```

This will set your user.name for git.